# Is it possible to have multiple timers in a multithreaded application in C Linux?

Tags: c, linux, timer, pthreads

I'm writing a simple test to analyze the behavior of a multithreaded application when using POSIX timers. 
I'm creating 3 threads, 3 timers, 3 events and 3 timerspecs. 
What I'm trying to do is have each thread set a timer, wait for the timer to expire (which releases an unsafe lock) and finish the threads.
However, when I run the following program only the first timer expires which leads me to believe that perhaps it's not possible to have more than one timer per process. Is something wrong?

`handle(union sigval params)` is the callback for each timer when they expire.

`threadTask(void *params)` is the callback executed by each thread.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <pthread.h>

typedef struct TH_PARAMS
{
    uint threadNum;
    pthread_t tid;
    timer_t *timer;
    struct sigevent *event;
} ThreadParams_t;

static timer_t timers[3];
static struct itimerspec timeToWait[3];
static struct sigevent events[3];
static ThreadParams_t thParams[3];
static char wait[3];

static void handle(union sigval params)
{
    ThreadParams_t *threadParams = (ThreadParams_t *) params.sival_ptr;
    printf("Timer %d expired. Thread num which sent %d. Thread %ld. Pthread %ld.\n",
       *((int*) *(threadParams->timer)), threadParams->threadNum,
       syscall(SYS_gettid), pthread_self());
    wait[threadParams->threadNum] = 0;
}

static void *threadTask(void *params)
{
    ThreadParams_t *threadParams = (ThreadParams_t *) params;

    printf("Thread num %d. Thread %ld. Pthread %ld.\n",
       threadParams->threadNum, syscall(SYS_gettid),
       pthread_self());

    if (0 != timer_settime(threadParams->timer, 0, &timeToWait[threadParams->threadNum], NULL))
    {
    printf("Failed to set timers. Error %d.\n", errno);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    while(wait) sleep(1);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    int i;

    printf("Main thread started. Thread: %ld. Pthread: %ld\n", syscall(SYS_gettid), pthread_self());

    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
    timeToWait[i].it_value.tv_sec = 2;
    timeToWait[i].it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
    timeToWait[i].it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    timeToWait[i].it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

    events[i].sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
    events[i].sigev_notify_function = handle;
    events[i].sigev_value.sival_ptr = &thParams[i];

    if (0 != timer_create(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &events[i], &timers[i]))
    {
        printf("Failed to create timers. Error %d.\n", errno);
        return 1;
    }

    wait[i] = 1;

    thParams[i].threadNum = i;
    thParams[i].event = &events[i];
    thParams[i].timer = &timers[i];

    if (0 != pthread_create(&thParams[i].tid, NULL, threadTask, (void *) &thParams[i]))
    {
        printf("Failed to create thread. Error %d.\n", errno);

        for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        {
        if (timers[i])
        {
            timer_delete(timers[i]);
        }
        }

        return 1;
    }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
    pthread_join(thParams[i].tid, NULL);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
    if (timers[i])
    {
        timer_delete(timers[i]);
    }
    }

    printf("Main thread finished. Thread: %ld.\n", syscall(SYS_gettid));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `man timer_create:  [...]The kernel preallocates a "queued real-time signal" for each timer created using timer_create().  Consequently, the number of timers is  limited by the RLIMIT_SIGPENDING resource limit (see setrlimit(2)).[...]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I found my mistake. I was not dereferencing the timer pointer.
In function `threadTask`, specifically in the `timer_settime` the first argument should be `*threadParams->timer`, emphasis on the *.